# Python: TypeError: an integer is required (got type module)

Tags: python

i have small code to read all image on folder and send them to current API alternately. but this code doesn't work yet, how to solve this problem. thankyou.

```
import cv2
import os
import json
import requests
import time

vehicle_count = [0]
current_path = os.getcwd() #+ "/"
file = '/image_folder/image' + str(len(vehicle_count)) + ".png"
path = '/home/username/Documents/path/to/image_folder%s' % file
temp_file = current_path + file
result = []

def send_image(source_image):
    cv2.imread(temp_file , source_image)
    vehicle_count.insert(0, 1)
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        response = requests.post(
            'https://url_to_API/',
            files=dict(upload=fp),
            headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'MY_API'})
        result.append(response.json())
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=2));

        with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(result, outfile)
    os.remove("%s" %temp_file)
```

and this is error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plate_detection_main.py", line 234, in <module>
    object_detection_function()     
  File "plate_detection_main.py", line 133, in object_detection_function
    line_thickness=1,
  File "/home/smartron01/Documents/tf-object-counting/vehicle_counting_tensorflow/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 515, in visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
    use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates) 
  File "/home/smartron01/Documents/tf-object-counting/vehicle_counting_tensorflow/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 128, in draw_bounding_box_on_image_array
    use_normalized_coordinates)
  File "/home/smartron01/Documents/tf-object-counting/vehicle_counting_tensorflow/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 182, in draw_bounding_box_on_image
    predicted_direction, predicted_speed,  is_vehicle_detected, update_csv = speed_prediction.predict_speed(top, bottom, right, left, current_frame_number, detected_vehicle_image, ROI_POSITION)
  File "/home/smartron01/Documents/tf-object-counting/vehicle_counting_tensorflow/utils/speed_and_direction_prediction_module/speed_prediction.py", line 46, in predict_speed
    image_api_sender.send_image(image_saver)  # send image to platerecognizer.com
  File "/home/smartron01/Documents/tf-object-counting/vehicle_counting_tensorflow/utils/image_utils/image_api_sender.py", line 15, in send_image
    cv2.imread(temp_file , source_image)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type module)
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Can you paste entire error traceback?

Comment: on ```cv2.imread(temp_file , source_image)``` line @Linda

Comment: @ThaerA yes, i added it above

Comment: how do you call the function? what is passed as `source_image` to the function? You can find the documentation on `imread()` [here](https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-read-image-cv2-imread/). As a side node, when combining paths and filenames, it is saver to use 'os.path.join(folder_path, filename)`.

Comment: @scalartensor Thanks, I added an answer below, if it answers your question, please mark it as answered otherwise let us know if it doesn't work.

Comment: thankyou @Linda, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `cv2.imread(temp_file , source_image)`, you're passing two arguments to the `imread()` function where only one is needed.  Try: `cv2.imread(temp_file)` given that temp_file is the correct path to the image file you want to load.

*Note: the second argument that you can pass to the imread(path, flag) function is flag which specifies the way in which image should be read. It’s default value is cv2.IMREAD_COLOR*

Comment: ah, thank you.. it help with a little code change, thankyou